# Preserve order of inputs to outputs, while each output comes from a file that should get read once

Tags: rust, caching, design-patterns, concurrency, computer-science

I'm struggling to come up with the best way to structure my program, regarding a specific function.

**Here are some details:**

- The input to the function is a vector of (latitude, longitude) coordinates

  - These can be in *whichever order the user supplies*
- The output of the function should be the elevations at the input coordinates, in the same order as the inputs
- The elevations are retrieved by accessing pixel values in TIFF files that are named by whole number latitude, longitude coordinates, e.g. `n40w106`, `n40w107`, ...

  - This number represents the top left corner, for example:

    - (39.5, -105.5), (39.8, -105.2) would both be in `n40w106.tif`
    - (40.3, -106.1), (40.5, -106.9) would both be in `n41w107.tif`
  - This means that multiple points in different spots in the input vector could need to be retrieved from the same file
- I already have the all of the functionality to take input points and retrieve the elevation from the corresponding files

What I am struggling with is these extra requirements that I want to ensure:

- Each file should only get loaded once
- Only one file should be in memory at a time (so I don't think caching will work)
- The order of the outputs should correspond to the order of the supplied inputs

**Is there some existing paradigm or concept in CS that achieves what I want?**

I'm also interested in if there is a model that works well with concurrency.
For reference, I am using the Rust programming language.

Comment: For that second bullet point, do you mean "only one file should be in memory at a time"?

Comment: Keep in mind that you could add sequence numbers to the to the given coordinates when you read them, then sort the coordinates into some order that makes the retreival of elevation data more efficient, and then finally sort the results back into the original sequence.

Comment: @drewtato, Yes that's a more concise way to explain it, edited

Answer (score 1):

Together, the requirements that each file should get loaded only once and that they should only be held in memory while being used means that you are going to have to determine ahead of time a set of groups that all come from the same file. Otherwise you cannot satisfy both constraints at once.

To preserve ordering, you can create the output buffer ahead of time. Then, when organizing the input list into groups, you can include its index within the input list so that the code processing that item can write it directly into the correct slot in the output buffer.

Finally, you send each group to a thread where all of the entries for a single file can be processed all at once.

Note that, due to Rust's aliasing rules, the threads will normally not be able to write to the buffer all at the same time without some kind of a mutex protecting it, even if they are writing to different indexes.  However, you can get around this issue by using `split_first_mut` with the output buffer, storing a mutable reference to where the output value should be stored. Then there is no aliasing, *and* no required mutex.

You will want to use [scoped threads](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.scope.html) as well so that you can send those mutable slices to the threads.

Finally, you return the output buffer.

Here is an example of a function that accepts a list of pairs of numbers `(a, b)` where the result of processing a pair is their product, but where all pairs with the same `b` value should be processed together:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn process_groups(items: &[(i32, i32)]) -> Vec<i32> {
    let mut output = vec![0; items.len()];
    let mut output_head = output.as_mut_slice();

    let mut groups: HashMap<i32, Vec<(i32, &mut i32)>> = HashMap::new();

    for &(a, b) in items {
        let (output_pos, tail) = output_head.split_first_mut().unwrap();
        output_head = tail;

        groups.entry(b).or_default().push((a, output_pos));
    }

    std::thread::scope(|s| {
        for (b, items) in groups {
            s.spawn(move || {
                for (a, output) in items {
                    *output = a * b;
                }
            });
        }
    });

    output
}

#[test]
fn example() {
    assert_eq!(
        process_groups(&[(2, 4), (16, 3), (7, 4), (9, 4), (25, 2), (18, 3),]),
        vec![2 * 4, 16 * 3, 7 * 4, 9 * 4, 25 * 2, 18 * 3]
    );
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=341225e1004294a401323d2243c1228b))

A few caveats to note here:

- Since your code needs to read from files, the processing function in your case is fallible. You will need a way to communicate errors back to the caller. You could have any error cause the whole operation to fail (return `Result<Vec<_>, _>`) or you could return as much as possible by allowing individual results to have failed (return `Vec<Result<_, _>>`).
- The example code assumes that you can construct a default value to fill the output buffer initially. If no such value exists, you may need to use `None` as the placeholder and fill it with `Some` values in your threads. Alternatively, there is a process that involves unsafe code and [`MaybeUninit`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html) where you can allocate the space needed for the items without using `Option` *or* initializing them ahead of time, but code to do it this way is hard to get right, and any bug in that code can cause soundness issues.
- The example code creates one thread per group. It may be more efficient to create a fixed number of threads and use a [channel](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/fn.channel.html) to queue the jobs to those threads instead.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response! One immediate reaction as I continue to grasp the answer: It would seem to me that tokio may be a better choice for concurrency, considering getting values involves file IO, and the computation I do to figure out the location of the data is fairly light (I only need to do an affine transform between geospatial->image coordinates, find which chunk to load out of the tiff from that, and access the proper index in that chunk's data). That also may be biased as I have worked with tokio and not std::thread though!

Comment: @KyleCarow Yes, Tokio would be a fine choice. You can process the groups as a stream using [`buffer_unordered`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.buffer_unordered) to provide the concurrency.

Comment: @KyleCarow tokio does not help with file based I/O, as it is blocking. Use regular threads.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I'm a bit confused by that comment. `tokio` by default uses multiple threads and has an async version of `fs`. The `tiff` crate incorporates it's own file reading though, so I'd plan to spawn a task that wraps the file read. It's also my understand that the only non-blocking file reading is done through `io_uring`, which is only available on recent linux kernels.

Comment: `tokio`does not use `io_uring` (there exists [`tokio-uring`](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio-uring) though). So it is basically a thread pool, but less efficient than a thread pool because of all of the async stuff.

Comment: To clarify, by wrapping the file read, I guess I mean using `spawn_blocking` to ensure that other tasks aren't blocked. But since I would be using `spawn_blocking` so often, wouldn't it make more sense to just use threads for each file chunk read anyway...? The more I try to learn about concurrency/multithreading, the less I know.